# Connect to database and use databases in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, ado.net

I'm new to using databases in C#. So I have some questions about it.

1) How I can connect an `Access` or `SQL Server` or `MySQL` files with C#?

2) Visual Studio lets me to create a mdf file (`SQL data base file`). When I create one mdf file, how can I use that? What's the difference between `access` or `Sql` files and `mdf` file?

3) `ADO.NET` has been created to work with databases, I think! Right? So is using `ADO.NET` a new way or easier way to connect and use data base file in C#? How can I use `ADO.Net`?

Comment: These aren't programming problems. You just need to read some documentation and follow some tutorials.

Comment: MS Access or SQLite are embedded database - you can treat it like a "file", usually the require no installation and can be easily deploy to client's machine. You want to use them if database shall be used locally, on client's machine only. SQL Server or MySql are "bigger" database systems, they require installation (some of them offer also portable versions, however). They offer better performance and more advanced features than embedded database, yet are harder do deploy: you use them usually installed on a server, which users are accessing via network.

Comment: @mj82: MS Access is **not** an embedded database

Comment: Indeed it's not. I've used a wrong word.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to start, using Microsofts words:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228366%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its overkill, but I've enjoyed using Entity Framework to create a data access layer for my applications.

If you check out some of the asp.net MVC tutorials out there, you'll find a "Code First/Only" method out there that allows you to create your database based on your the objects you create for your application.